# I need some help it's about a face recognition python opencv module

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to do a face recognition that can detect faces and for some weird reason my code is giving me error
the error :

```
 line 13, in <module>
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build- 
m8us58q4\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in 
function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

the code itself:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Cascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,640) # set Width
cap.set(4,480) # set Height
while True:
    ret , img = cap.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img,-1)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
     gray,
     
     scaleFactor=1.2,
     minNeighbors=5,
     minSize = (20,20)
    )
    
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    cv2.imshow('video',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27: # pressing esc in order to quit 
        break
cap.release()
cap.destroyAllWindows()
```

I would be very happy if some of the people who may read this will send me their solution by the way I'm very sorry about my indentation I'm just kinda new to stack overflow

Comment: Sounds like `img == None`. Print out the value of img to make sure you're getting an image from the camera.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question? ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your VideoCapture() did not grab frames.
Try to check the script on a saved video first (VideoCapture("vid_name.mp4")).

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the `cv2.flip()` and see if it helps, if yes, perhaps try move this flipping to after converting the source frame to gray.
Also it is a good idea to check the value of `ret` in `ret, frame = cap.read()` by using

```
if not ret:
    print('no frame')
    break
```

Then if the program exits with this error message, it means there's something wrong with the camera connection.

Comment: Thank very much ! well I find out that I've been mistaken with my previous xml file lol you see I'm working with a lot of jsons and xml files and anyways thank you very much (:

Answer (score 0):

Modifying code like this worked for me. Putting the frame part outside the loop and then continuing:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Cascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,640) # set Width
cap.set(4,480) # set Height

ret , img = cap.read()
img = cv2.flip(img,-1)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
while True:
    if ret == False:
        continue
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
     gray,
     
     scaleFactor=1.2,
     minNeighbors=5,
     minSize = (20,20)
    )
    
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    cv2.imshow('video',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27: # pressing esc in order to quit 
        break
cap.release()
cap.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the error message you posted: The issue is the the HaarCascade classifer did not properly load due to the syntax in the load command. I was able to get it to work by

- making sure I hade the file: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml
- placing it into a known directory and modifying the load command to match.

...

```
import numpy as np
import cv2




faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('c:\\Cascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,640) # set Width
cap.set(4,480) # set Height

ret , img = cap.read()
img = cv2.flip(img,-1)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
while True:
    if ret == False:
        continue
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray,scaleFactor=1.2,minNeighbors=5,minSize = (20,20))
    
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    cv2.imshow('video',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27: # pressing esc in order to quit 
        break
cap.release()
cap.destroyAllWindows()
```